# Shortcode - Taxonomy terms list with ACF term icon

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to create a [shortcode] that will display taxonomy terms of a post in a list with an icon.

I am using ACF for the icon with meta `book_icon`, then trying to call it into the shortcode following the [ACF forum post here](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/taxonomy-term-image/).

This is my code so far:

```
add_shortcode( 'show-books', 'books_output' );
function books_output($atts){

    ob_start();
    echo '<ul class="books-terms">';

    global $post;
$taxonomy = 'books';
$terms = get_the_terms( $post, $taxonomy );
$image = get_field('book_icon');

if ( !empty( $terms ) ) {
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        echo '<li><img src="' . $image['url'] . '" class="book-css-class">' . $term->name . '</li>';
    }
}
    echo '</ul>';
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    return $output;
}
```

I'm getting the taxonomy terms in a list, but not the image icon.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `$image_id = get_field('book_icon', $term, false);` - there is no `$term` at this point - you are only creating that variable further down, with `foreach ($terms as $term)`. Since you want an individual icon for each term (presumably?), getting this meta field value and the image based on that, belong _into_ the loop in the first place.

Comment: You should really have `WP_DEBUG` set true during development - PHP error reporting would have alerted you that $term did not exist in this place. https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/

Comment: Hey 04FS , thanks. I have updated the code now ( based on more research and alternative solutions ) the WP_DEBUG is now on. I'm not getting any error, but still can't make the updated code work. The Chrome developer console says the says <img src(unknown) class="book-css-class">

Comment: That does not reflect what I said. Now you are still trying to get the `book_icon` field before the loop, but since you left out any ID, it will use the ID of the global $post object now. This is not really what you want, if I got you correctly - you are not looking for an icon that is associated with the post, but with each individual term of the post - no?

Comment: Plus, you are not even using `wp_get_attachment_image_src` any more - so do you have the ACF field configured to return only the image source URL now, in "formatted" mode? (Not sure what it returns then, just the plain URL I suppose - then that would have to be `$image` only in the output part, not `$image['url']`.)